# Markers with customs angle values

Tags: leaflet, javascript, markers

I'm trying to make some markers spinnable using this :

```
target = document.getElementById("mapid");
target.ondragover = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
};

target.ondrop = function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    imagePath = e.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
    coordinates = mymap.containerPointToLatLng(L.point([e.clientX,e.clientY]));
    L.marker(coordinates, {icon: L.icon({iconUrl: imagePath, iconSize: [60,40]}),draggable: true}).addTo(mymap);
};
var angle = 0;
var width = 60;
var height = 40;

$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which == 65){angle-=5;left();angle = 0;}; //"A" key
    if(e.which == 69){angle+=5;right();angle = 0;}; //"E" key
    if(e.which == 83){height+=5;bigger();}; //"S" key
    if(e.which == 90){height-=5;smaller();}; //"Z" key
    if(e.which == 81){ width-=5;thinner();}; //"Q" key
    if(e.which == 68){ width+=5;wider();}; //"D" key
    if(e.which == 87){ $('.leaflet-marker-icon').attr('id', 'rotate');}; //"W" key
    if(e.which == 88){ $('.leaflet-marker-icon').removeAttr('id');}; //"X" key
});

function left(){document.getElementById('rotate').style.transform += "rotate("+angle+"deg)";};
function right(){document.getElementById('rotate').style.transform += "rotate("+angle+"deg)";};
function smaller(){document.getElementById('rotate').style.height = height + 'px'};
function bigger(){document.getElementById('rotate').style.height = height + 'px'};
function wider(){document.getElementById('rotate').style.width = width + 'px'};
function thinner(){document.getElementById('rotate').style.width = width + 'px'};
```

**PROBLEMS :**

- Only the first dropped marker can rotate, readjusts its size
- I can rotate my marker as I want, it will now stays in place, but If I drag the icon around, zoom/unzoom the map, the `rotate(Value)` will be gone forever.

**What I've tried and didn't work:**

- replace the ID with some sort of class (makes ALL the elements adjustable at the exam same time)
- a keybind to remove the ID from the current marker (after a new marker is dropped, the ID will be set for the first one)

**What I want:** multiples markers that can rotate, and modify their size.

**UPDATES**: I found why my marker keeps losing thr `rotate` function when dragging it, zooming in/out, it's simply bcz these actions are modifying the `translate3d` values, thus removing the `rotate` style

Comment: Also, I've realized that if a marker that has been readjust, the width and height will be returned (not what I want too) for the next marker

Comment: You should try out this plugin: https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.RotatedMarker

Comment: How should I use it since `setRotationAngle` is not a function ?

Comment: Manage to make it work, thanks ! **BUT**, I'll have at least 2 markers on the map, and I've found that **ALL** markers will rotate at the exact same time...
I only want one marker to rotate at a time @Stefan_Fairphone